# How to move files from specific folders only using powershell

Tags: powershell

My code below moves databases from one location to another location:

```
$filters = Get-Content "c:\customerName.txt"
$source = "\\Server1\Databases"
$destination = "\\Server2\Databases"

    foreach($filter in $filters)
        {
        Get-Childitem $source -include *.* -Recurse`
        | ? {!$_.PsIsContainer -and $_.fullname -match $filter} `
        | % { 

    Move-Item  $_.FullName -Destination $destination"\$filter" 
        }
    }
```

The code works absolutely fine, but I need to change it so that it doesnt move files from a specific folder i.e. `\\Server1\Databases\AMG`

So am trying to edit the above code as following:

```
foreach($filter in $filters)
    {
    Get-Childitem $source -include *.* -Recurse | where {$_.source -notlike *"\\Server1\Databases\AMG"*} `
    | ? {!$_.PsIsContainer -and $_.fullname -match $filter} `
    | % { 

Move-Item  $_.FullName -Destination $destination"\$filter" 
    }
}
```

But if I run the code, it moves everything including the stuff from `\\Server1\Databases\AMG`

How can I fix this code to work as it is supposed to? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change:

```
Get-Childitem $source -include *.* -Recurse | where {$_.source -notlike *"\\Server1\Databases\AMG"*}
```

To:

```
Get-Childitem $source -include *.* -Recurse | where {$_.fullname -notlike "*\\Server1\Databases\AMG*"}
```

- There is no `.source` property returned by `Get-Childitem`. Instead you could use `.fullname` which is the full path for each file or folder.
- You should put the `*` wildcard characters inside the quote marks.